# Entity Framework ConnectionString Parsing Exception

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, connection-string

I can't find how my connectionString syntax is wrong. Can anyone suggest a way to figure this out? I am having a difficulty using EF with my connection string. I am new to EF.

- I am using Sybase Anywhere 12 database.
- I'm using the Table-First ObjectContext with EDMX in a separate class library refenced by a web application.
- I'm using a Ninject Module in my class library to bind my repositories.
- I'm using a ODBC DataStore called "Test"
- Other information EF 4.3.1.0, .NET 4, VS2010
- My main web application web.config has the EF connection string copied to it as:

`<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Entities"connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyEntities.csdl|res://*/MyEntities.ssdl|res://*/MyEntities.msl;provider=iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere;provider connection string=&quot;UserID=aUser;Password=aPassword;DataSourceName=Test&quot;" providerName="iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere"/>
</connectionStrings>`

When I initialize my Entity/ObjectContext in my Repository (see using statement below) it returns an error: "The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid."

```
        using (var context = new Entities())
        {
           return {Linq to Entity here}
        }
```

I turned on CLR exceptions on the debugger and found the code throws the error in the .NET Framework here:

EntityConnection.cs

effectiveConnectionOptions = new DbConnectionOptions(setting.ConnectionString, EntityConnectionStringBuilder.Synonyms, false);

edmx designer generated:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new Entities object using the connection string found in the 'Entities' section of the application configuration file.
        /// </summary>
        public Entities() : base("name=Entities", "Entities")
        {
            this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            OnContextCreated();
        }
```

I can see my connection string there, so it is having a difficult time parsing the connectionString. I have tried many different permutations of syntax and haven't found anything it accepts including:

- Explicitly naming the assembly for entity files instead of a wildcard(e.g. metadata=res://MyDomain/MyEntities.csdl...)
- Using Sybase friendly ODBC attributes such as UID instead of UserID, PWD instead of Password, and DBN instead of DataSourceName.

Thanks.

Comment: how do you actually set the connection string? how your connection actually looks like?

Comment: Sorry, connection string needed special html chars to display. It should now display fine.

Comment: Thanks. I think I was not clear enough - can you show the constuctor of the `Entities` class to show how the connection string is set? Did you write this code on your own or was it generated by VS?

Comment: @Pawel See edited code above. It was generated by the EDMX designer.

Comment: @Pawel I copy and paste the connectionstring from the edmx into the web.config of the web app replacing the double quotes in the provider string with the xml friendly &quot;

Comment: Mistated EF version. Now should be correct above. 4.3.1.0

Comment: Can you try using `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"` instead of `providerName="iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere"` in your connection string? The `provider=iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere` inside connectionString attribute should be left intact.

Comment: @Pawel Thanks for your comments! It helped me to actually post this because it made me rethink everything. I did not try your solution. EF did take the SA provider just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got everything working and the only reason I can think of is that I deleted my ASP .NET 4.0 temp files. Also, I must add I changed my process from using an integration test to test this piece to using a unit test. I did not do unit tests first, because our build server does not have a database on it.

Once I was able to prove that it was working there, I decided to delete my temp files. After that, everything started working properly. So, some sort of cache issue was occurring in my application. I used the same connectionString that I mentioned above.

Actually, I used the domain name of the Metadata "metadata=res://MyDomain/MyEntitities.csdl" rather than */MyEntities.csdl. I don't plan on changing the domain any time soon. In fact, that is just what may have caused some of the issue, because I had changed the location, name, and namespace of MyEntities.Domain where the EF was.